# Two 4-bit bitfields don't add up to size of one byte - how to fix?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I try to port a library from linux to win32, there is a struct defined as:

```
struct X {
    unsigned int    type : 4;
    unsigned int    tag : 4;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

The size should be 1, I changed it to:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct X {
    unsigned int    type : 4;
    unsigned int    tag : 4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

But the sizeof(X) it is still 4, the encoding would be messed up, how can I change the size to 1 ?

Comment: Just use a single `uint8_t` field with a couple of methods to get / set tag and type instead of bit fields (which are always a pain to deal with)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned int`:

```
struct X {
    unsigned char type : 4;
    unsigned char tag : 4;
};

static_assert(sizeof(X)==1);
```

Comment: But why `int` doesn't work? Shouldn't it use only specified bits according to the standard? Is this implementation defined or a bug in VS?

Comment: @taskinoor: It is implementation defined. MSVC pays more respect to the base type. And it actually uses this type for accessing. So, if the type is `unsigned int`, it will access the bit field with 32-bit operations (even if the field is just 4 bits wide).